# Canvas calculating area

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, canvas, qml

I am a newbie to QT but have a bit of experience with C++. this is my first project with Qt and QML.

I want to develop a program that lets the user draw on a canvas (see picture below) and I would like to calculate the area of each contour. I figured out how-to-draw on a canvas.

Example 1 Picture shows a Red rectangle which is the canvas area where the user will do a free-form sketch. The user draws the black free-form sketch.
Now I would like to calculate the area on the left and right contour. User will always only draw from one edge to another edge.

[image: Example 1]

Below is another example of the free-form sketch. In the following sketch, I need to calculate the area of the three contours.

[image: Example 2]

also, the contours can intersect with the same edge and other contour.

[image: Example 3]

**My question is, what is the best way to calculate the area of each contour?**

**should I use a contour detection algorithm or OpenCV?
any thoughts on how i should tackle this problem.**

My initial thoughts are

1. start at canvas position (0,0) and start counting until I reach one point drawn by the user and repeat until I reach the end

After watching a couple of YouTube videos, I figured out the interaction between C++ and QML. now I can access the mouse position in C++. (see code below)

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "canvasarea.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

    QScopedArrayPointer<CanvasArea> canvasArea(new CanvasArea);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("canvasArea", canvasArea.data());

    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Row {
        id: colorTools
        anchors {
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            top: parent.top
            topMargin: 8
        }

        property color paintColor: "#000000"
        spacing: 4

        Button {
            text: "Clear"
            onClicked: {
                canvas.clear()
                canvasArea.clearCanvas();
            }
        }

    }

    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: canvas
        border.color: "#ff0000"
        border.width: 4;
    }

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        width: 640
        height: 480
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            top: colorTools.bottom
            margins: 8
        }

        property real lastX
        property real lastY
        property color color: colorTools.paintColor

        function clear() {
            var ctx = getContext('2d')
            ctx.reset();
            canvas.requestPaint();
        }

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext('2d')
            ctx.lineWidth = 1.5
            ctx.strokeStyle = canvas.color
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY)
            lastX = area.mouseX
            lastY = area.mouseY
            ctx.lineTo(lastX, lastY)
            ctx.stroke()
            canvasArea.mouseCordinates(lastX, lastY)
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: area
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                canvas.lastX = mouseX
                canvas.lastY = mouseY
            }
            onPositionChanged: {
                canvas.requestPaint()
            }
        }
    }


}
```

canvasarea.cpp

```
#include "canvasarea.h"
#include <QDebug>

CanvasArea::CanvasArea(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void CanvasArea::mouseCordinates(int x, int y)
{
    QPoint point(x , y);
    userContourLocations.append(point);
    qDebug() << "currentCursorPositon" << point;
}

void CanvasArea::clearCanvas()
{
    userContourLocations.clear();
}
```

Comment: Can it intersect itself or other contours? SInce as I understand the contour may be of any complexity - it may as well be a labyrinth as long as it ends on an edge - the only problem is determining which segments of the canvas belong to which area. For that please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill alhorithms. I think canvas fill() can do the trick (you can first copy image to an invisible canvas) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill . Then you only need to count colored pixels. Is this enough of an explanation?

Comment: @JackWhite yes contours can intersect with the same edge and other contours. please see my post again, I have added an example of the intersections.

Comment: Ok you can approach it from 2 angles: 1) "vector" way - more precise and probably much faster way in most cases but requires more studying+coding: use some sort of contour/area detection algorithm - openCV or otherwise. In this case you store each path (that is - a coord list for the contour) and export it into an array. Then the question is not about QML but more about vector graphics algorithms - you should rephrase your question to someth like "what algorithm should I use for..." with tags like "vector-graphics". 2) Raster way: canvas.fill(), count pixels. Slow and stupid but less work.

Comment: Actually, I'm unfamiliar with openCV but it seems to only be about raster image processing. Am I missing something here? Is this just a mockup for something that must detect contours from photos or similar? In that case you should first ask about that, again independent of Qt or QML: "How to detect contours of images?" and include real example images. After that you apply area-detection algorithms. If your goal is to process paths drawn by user with a mouse then you don't need to detect contours (or OpenCV) - you already know them - just put each mouse X and Y into an array.